# Stopping CATransition animation

Tags: iphone, catransition

I'm using this code to make ripple animation for my view

```
transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.delegate = self;
    transition.duration = 3;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    NSString *types[4] = {@"cube", @"rippleEffect", @"cube", @"alignedCube"};
    NSString *subtypes[4] = {kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromRight};
    transition.type = types[1];
    transition.subtype = subtypes[1];
```

Now I want to stop the animation by means of tap and after that I want to start from the view where I stopped....

I tried for

[view.layer removeAllAnimations];

But I found the following thing doesn't work ..Any Suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

Set the speed of your animation to 0 to pause it and to 1 to resume it again.
Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1673.html

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the current animation state from the CALayer.

```
   #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

   myView.layer.modelLayer.frame = myView.layer.presentationLayer.frame;
```

Comment: @B Visschers    Y I need this?

Comment: If you want to stop the animation in the middle, and keep things as they are (not reset the view to before the animation started), then you need this.

Comment: There are other ways to do this. Check the extensive documentation about [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).